# Angularjs Ng-repeat by mongoose date.now?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongoose, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to order an ng-repeat directive by the time of the last message sent in my inbox. Here is the structure of a "conversation"

```
var message = new Schema({
    message: String,
    date: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});

 var conversationSchema = new Schema({
    messages: [message] //list of messages
});
```

My inbox is an array of "Conversations". I would like to order it by the date of the last message. I have tried the following:

**controller:**

```
$scope.inbox = [conversations] // assume full of conversations
```

**html:**

```
<div ng-repeat="c in inbox | orderBy: 'c.messages[c.messages.length - 1].date':true"></div>
```

I expected the ordering to work but it does the same ordering it is in the array that is in the controller. I suspect that it doesn't know how to order by mongoose's date.now?